# How to find the intersection(/s) of two curves(non-linear and linear) in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have two plots using scatter plot of which one is non linear and the other one is linear. And I require the intersection of these curves. How should I proceed ?

Edit: The plots are done by using a set of values in excel.

Curve 1:

x: 0,
0.5,
1,
1.5,
2,
2.5,
3,
3.5,
4,
4.5,
5,
5.5,
6,
6.5,
7,
7.5,
8

y:8.43,
8.76,
8.27,
7.87,
7.69,
7.76,
8.46,
8.85,
8.34,
7.92,
7.73,
7.79,
8.42,
8.76,
8.27,
7.87,
7.69

Curve 2: y=8.168

Thanks

Edit-2: In the other question [Get coordinates of intersecting point of two trend lines](https://superuser.com/questions/1111959/get-coordinates-of-intersecting-point-of-two-trend-lines) a trend line is made and then the intersection of those are dealt, which is clearly not possible for mine and ***not a duplicate***  for the question you are referring to.

Comment: Same question https://superuser.com/q/1111959

Comment: You mean you want the intersection ***s**,* right?  It looks likes there’s more than one.  Otherwise, you haven’t explained your problem very well.

Comment: Yes intersection**s**, but the first intersection point will also do the job.

Comment: I tried the one you are referring to <https://superuser.com/questions/1111959/get-coordinates-of-intersecting-point-of-two-trend-lines>  does'nt apply to my case, as when i try the trend lines only moving average with period 2 matches and I cannot get the equation out of it.

Comment: @Máté Juhász, and others, this is **not** a duplicate of the referenced question.  He *could* compute the intersection of the trendline through the cyclic curve with the constant "curve", but that intersection is NOT what he's trying to find. See the graph in my answer below.  Thanks

Comment: @Biswa its not exact duplicate of the same question. Its a different one and please see the edit 2 to know the difference. 
And I recently got to know about an extension, numpy in excel which does the interpolation job correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:  The following approach is applicable *only* to graphs where linear interpolation is appropriate **and** where the linear curve is a constant horizontal line.

Assuming your data is in columns A,B and C as shown below, the x-coordinate of the intersections can be found using the formula below.  This formula filled down from D3 gives the results in the table below.

```
=IF(OR(AND($B2>=$C3,$B3<=$C3),AND($B2<=$C3,$B3>=$C3)),$A2+($A3-$A2)*($B2-$C3)/($B2-$B3),"")
```

[image]

If you would *clearly* explain your requirements, you might get an acceptable solution.

---

---

Here's the graph with a linear fit to the first curve (red line) and the second (constant) curve (purple line).

[image]

You can approach this in couple of ways:

1. You can solve the equation of the linear fit for x when y = 8.168. 
   That gives the point where the two straight lines cross (4.040,
   8.168).
2. You can find the points where the blue curve equals 8.168.  The
   simplest way to do this is by linear interpolation, which assumes
   that the line segments between points can be approximated by a
   straight line.  For the first intersection (between points 3 and 4)
   8.168 is this fraction of the way between the two points:

   `(8.27-8.168)/(8.27-7.87) = 0.255`

And the x-coordinate is the same fraction of the way between 1 and 1.5, giving (1.128, 8.168).

The third crossing is coincidentally near the intersection with the linear fit, so let's see what it is, too:

`(8.34-8.168)/(8.34-7.92) = 0.4095`

and the third intersection is at (4.205, 8.168).

Comment: In first method, it gives only one point of intersection that too not in the range whichever i need,
 
And yes second method works, but that's a manual way of observation and interpolating, which is a very crude way, and yes i use this for the time being, but when there are many a points, I need a way in excel which accurately gives the results.
Thanks

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: Very appropriate username you have there.

Comment: Thanks it suffices my need. Sorry for the username if its inappropriate.